# how to use different output logger files in java?

Tags: java, file, logging, handler, multipleoutputs

I am trying to have two output loggers in my gui. This code correctly outputs to each file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Handler handler = new FileHandler("OutFile.log");
        Logger.getLogger("myApp").addHandler(handler);
        Logger.getLogger("myApp").setUseParentHandlers(false);
        Handler handler2 = new FileHandler("User.log");
        handler2.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        Logger.getLogger("User").addHandler(handler2);
        Logger.getLogger("User").setUseParentHandlers(false);


        Logger.getLogger("myApp").severe("AppStarting");
        Logger.getLogger("User").severe("UserLogStarting");
```

But afterwards when I test the same two lines in the gui it does not work anymore. Is my interpretation of the logger wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Instead if I use the below line in the main (so I removed myApp from the string) then the logger works perfectly throughout the app, but everything goes to one file only.

```
    Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(handler);
```

P.S. I don't want to use a third party class if I can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the Logger been returned by Logger.getLogger() to a Logger object, like this:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("myApp");
```

and then use log to work. Otherwise Logger.getLogger() will always return a new instance.

Comment: Thanks, I might have known it'd be something daft I was missing, for others stuck with the same, I added:   
    `private final static Logger userLog = Logger.getLogger("User");
    private final static Logger errorLog = Logger.getLogger("myApp");
` before starting my main